# Workflow foundation: Get the termination reason in Asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is there any way to get the Termination Reason that is inserted into the TerminateWorkflow activity inside an ASP .NET application?. For example the following doesnt works.

```
 app.Completed =(e) =>
                {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Exception:" + o.Reason.GetType().FullName + o.Reason.Message);
            syncEvent.Set();
        };
```

Does anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: I think it should be the e.TerminationException.Message

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the app.Aborted event instead.